# adding app to facebook page

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-apps

I'm new to facebook apps, and actually all I want is to add a 'contact us' tab to a 'like page' that I'm helping to manage. I have setup a server with PHP code, and opened an facebook app. (I left the SSL part empty because my server dose not support SSL.) And now I'm just trying to add the app to the page, but I can't find where... It's probably just a link I haven't noticed yet, but I can't find it.

I've googled around the internet, but all explanations I found where old, and didn't help me.

Just for clearness: I want to know how to add an existing facebook app to an existing facebook page

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&display=popup&next=YOUR_URL
```

Here the documentation
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/

Comment: I read that, but I can't find `YOUR_URL`. Where is that? And I didn't create a new user for my page, so how will it now which of my pages it should be added? (I'm an admin in more that one page)

Comment: YOUR_URL = http://yourdomain.com/your_app_folder/

when you insert this link in your browser address bar a windows will open and you can choose from all the pages you are admin where add the tab.